# window resize function only one time for specific window size

Tags: jquery

Hi all I need that if window is less then `768px` alert some and if window is more than `768px` alert some, I have this script and `else if(){}` not work when window size is more than `768px`
p.s. I need this heppend always when window is less then `768px` or more than `768px`

```
var i = 0;
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(width < 768 && i == 0){
        alert('less than 768px');
        i++;
        alert(i);
    }else if(width > 768){
        alert('more than 768px');
        i==0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of `i==0;` it should be `i=0;` inside `else if()` because you are assigning value `0` to `i`.

Although i don't know why actually you are using `i` but your complete code should look like :-

```
var i = 0;
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(width < 768 && i == 0){
        alert('less than 768px');
        i = 1;
    }else if(width > 768 && i == 1){
        alert('more than 768px');
        i = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: `else if(width > 768 && i == 1){
  alert('more than 768px');
  i=0;
  }`

Comment: I need after else if var `i = 0`;

Comment: resize function works always when window is resized by 1px
I need when window is less then 768px alert happend only one time and when more than 768px 1 time and it should be happend every time 
@Karikeya

Comment: @valkharitonashvili...yes..that is handled by `resize` method itself you need not to worry about that just exclude `i` from code and it will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    if(width < 768 && i == 0){
        alert('less than 768px');
        i = 1;
    }else if(width > 768){
        alert('more than 768px');        
    }
});
```

Comment: Use this Code...if the Window width less than 768 the if part executed only one time.....

Comment: and if window is more than 768?

Comment: if more than 768 . when ever the size is changed greater than 768 the else block fired...